# Search Functionality in IOS TVML application

Tags: ios, tvml

I have developed a TVML application. I need few changes in the code. Please find the github link for code.

I am developing IOS TV App which catalog template to display videos from remote server. Also need to implement search and layover functionality.

https://github.com/TVMLBegnr/TVMLApp

Videos array displays list of videos, On selection one video, other videos should display in overlay. Search functionality should work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your code directly in your question, rather than linking to it?

Answer (score 0):

Please include the code in the post. Do not use link or reference to the other websites because that can change and can make this discussion irrelevant.

You may want to download this Sample Code from Apple.

1. Create a Search controller class

### See sample Controller

```
class SearchController extends DocumentController {

setupDocument(document) {
    super.setupDocument(document);

    // Obtain references to some useful elements in the searchTemplate
    const searchTemplateElem = document.getElementsByTagName('searchTemplate').item(0);
    const searchFieldElem = document.getElementsByTagName('searchField').item(0);
    const separatorElem = document.getElementsByTagName('separator').item(0);
    const messageElem = document.getElementById("message");
    const suggestionsElem = document.getElementById("suggestions");
    const defaultResultsElem = document.getElementById("defaultResults");
    const resultsModeElem = document.getElementById("resultsMode");
    const resultsListElem = document.getElementById("resultsList");
    const resultsShelfContainerElem = document.getElementById("resultsShelfContainer");
    const resultsGridContainerElem = document.getElementById("resultsGridContainer");
    const resultsSectionElem = document.getElementById("resultsSection");

    // Clean up the document for initial presentation
    let resultsContainerElem = resultsShelfContainerElem;
    resultsListElem.removeChild(resultsGridContainerElem);
    toggleDefaultResults(true);

    // Define some search-related constants
    const searchBaseURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?";
    const searchResultsLimit = 25;
    const searchMediaType = "movie";
    const searchMediaArtworkWidth = 250;
    const searchMediaArtworkAspectRatio = 1.5;
    const searchMediaTitleFunc = function(item) {
        return item.trackCensoredName || item.trackName ||
               item.collectionCensoredName || item.collectionName;
    };
    const searchMediaItemIDFunc = function(item) {
        return item.trackId || item.collectionId;
    };
    const searchMediaArtworkURLFunc = function(item) {
        let result = item.artworkUrl60;
        if (typeof result === "string") {
            // WORKAROUND: Obtain high-resolution artwork
            result = result.replace("/60x60", "/600x600");
        }
        return result;
    };

    // Retain the XHR between searches so it can be cancelled mid-flight
    let searchRequest;
    // Retain the query between searches to determine changes
    let searchTextCache;
    // Retain the result items to handle selection events
    const searchResultsCache = [];

    const searchKeyboard = searchFieldElem.getFeature("Keyboard");
    // Register an event handler for search input changes
    searchKeyboard.onTextChange = performSearchRequest;

    // Register an event handler for search result mode selection
    resultsModeElem.addEventListener("highlight", function(event) {
        const selectedElement = event.target;
        const selectedMode = selectedElement.getAttribute("value");
        setResultsMode(selectedMode);
    });

    // Register an event handler for search suggestions selection
    suggestionsElem.addEventListener("select", function(event) {
        const selectedElement = event.target;
        const searchValue = selectedElement.getAttribute("value");
        searchKeyboard.text = searchValue;
        performSearchRequest();
    });

    // Register an event handler for search result selection
    resultsSectionElem.addEventListener("select", function(event) {
        const selectedElement = event.target;
        const resultIndex = selectedElement.getAttribute("resultIndex");
        const resultItem = searchResultsCache[resultIndex];
        handleSelectionForItem(resultItem);
    });

    /*
     * Show or hide the message in the search body.
     * Sets the content of the message if it is to be shown.
     */
    function toggleSearchMessage(bool, message) {
        if (bool) {
            // Set the message text
            if (message) {
                messageElem.textContent = message;
            }
            // Show the message if it's hidden
            if (!messageElem.parentNode) {
                searchTemplateElem.appendChild(messageElem);
            }
            toggleModeButtons(false);
        } else {
            // Hide the message if it's visible
            if (messageElem.parentNode) {
                searchTemplateElem.removeChild(messageElem);
            }
            toggleModeButtons(true);
        }
    }

    function toggleSearchSuggestions(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            // Show the suggestions if they're hidden
            if (!suggestionsElem.parentNode) {
                searchTemplateElem.appendChild(suggestionsElem);
            }
            toggleSearchMessage(false);
            toggleModeButtons(false);
        } else {
            // Hide the suggestions if they're visible
            if (suggestionsElem.parentNode) {
                searchTemplateElem.removeChild(suggestionsElem);
            }
            toggleModeButtons(true);
        }
    }

    function toggleDefaultResults(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            // Swap the default results in for the container
            if (resultsContainerElem.parentNode) {
                resultsListElem.removeChild(resultsContainerElem);
                resultsListElem.appendChild(defaultResultsElem);
            }
            toggleSearchMessage(false);
            toggleSearchSuggestions(false);
            toggleModeButtons(false);
        } else {
            // Swap the default results out and the container in
            if (!resultsContainerElem.parentNode) {
                resultsListElem.removeChild(defaultResultsElem);
                resultsListElem.appendChild(resultsContainerElem);
            }
            toggleModeButtons(true);
        }
    }

    function toggleModeButtons(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            if (!separatorElem.parentNode) {
                searchTemplateElem.appendChild(separatorElem);
            }
        } else {
            if (separatorElem.parentNode) {
                searchTemplateElem.removeChild(separatorElem);
            }
        }
    }

    function setResultsMode(mode) {
        // Remove existing results container
        while (resultsListElem.firstChild) {
            resultsListElem.removeChild(resultsListElem.firstChild);
        }
        // Determine the new results container element
        if (mode === "shelf") {
            resultsContainerElem = resultsShelfContainerElem;
        }
        if (mode === "grid") {
            resultsContainerElem = resultsGridContainerElem;
        }
        // Show the new results container in the collectionList
        resultsListElem.appendChild(resultsContainerElem);
        resultsContainerElem.appendChild(resultsSectionElem);
    }

    function performSearchRequest() {
        // Strip leading, trailing, and multiple whitespaces from the query
        const searchText = searchKeyboard.text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ");

        // Do nothing if the query hasn't meaningfully changed
        if (searchTextCache && searchText === searchTextCache) {
            return;
        }
        // Retain this query for the next time the input changes
        searchTextCache = searchText;

        // If there's already a search in-progress, cancel it.
        if (searchRequest && searchRequest.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            searchRequest.abort();
        }

        // Show the initial message and stop if there's no search query
        if (searchText.length === 0) {
            toggleDefaultResults(true);
            return;
        }

        // Build the URL for the search query
        const searchParams = [
            `media=${searchMediaType}`,
            `limit=${searchResultsLimit}`,
            `term=${encodeURIComponent(searchText)}`
        ].join("&");
        const searchURL = searchBaseURL + searchParams;

        // Perform the search request
        searchRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        searchRequest.open("GET", searchURL);
        searchRequest.responseType = "json";
        searchRequest.onload = showSearchResponse;
        searchRequest.onerror = showSearchError;
        searchRequest.send();

        searchFieldElem.setAttribute("showSpinner", true);
    }

    /*
     * Show a generic error message in the search body
     */
    function showSearchError() {
        toggleSearchMessage(true, "An error occurred during your search.");
        searchFieldElem.setAttribute("showSpinner", false);
    }

    /*
     * Parse the XHR response and show the results or a message
     */
    function showSearchResponse() {
        // Prepare the document for new search results
        toggleDefaultResults(false);
        toggleSearchSuggestions(false);
        clearSearchResults();
        searchFieldElem.setAttribute("showSpinner", false);

        // Show the results (or lack thereof)
        const searchResponse = searchRequest.response;
        const searchResults = searchResponse.results;
        if (searchResults.length > 0) {
            appendSearchResults(searchResults);
            toggleSearchMessage(false);
        } else {
            if (searchTextCache.length > 3) {
                toggleSearchMessage(true, `No results for ${searchTextCache}.`);
            } else {
                toggleSearchSuggestions(true);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Empty the results cache and remove all results lockup elements.
     */
    function clearSearchResults() {
        searchResultsCache.length = 0;
        // Remove all existing search results
        while (resultsSectionElem.firstChild) {
            resultsSectionElem.removeChild(resultsSectionElem.firstChild);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Create lockup elements for the search results and cache
     * the data to be referenced by the selection handler.
     */
    function appendSearchResults(results) {
        const startIndex = searchResultsCache.length;
        // Create new lockups for the results
        results.forEach(function(item, index) {
            index += startIndex;
            // Create item lockup element
            const lockupElem = document.createElement("lockup");
            // Set the result array index on the lockup
            lockupElem.setAttribute("resultIndex", index);
            // Populate the lockup element details
            populateLockupWithItem(lockupElem, item);
            // Add the lockup to the results collection
            resultsSectionElem.appendChild(lockupElem);
            // Add the item to the search results cache
            searchResultsCache.push(item);
        });
    }

    /*
     * Inserts elements containing data from a search result into the
     * empty lockup element created to display the result.
     * Shows an image, title, and subtitle in the lockup.
     */
    function populateLockupWithItem(lockupElem, item) {
        // Determine the lockup image attributes
        const titleText = searchMediaTitleFunc(item);
        const itemID = searchMediaItemIDFunc(item);
        const imgURL = searchMediaArtworkURLFunc(item);
        const imgWidth = searchMediaArtworkWidth;
        const imgHeight = imgWidth * searchMediaArtworkAspectRatio;
        // Create the child nodes of the lockup element
        const imgElem = document.createElement("img");
        const titleElem = document.createElement("title");
        // Set the lockup image attributes
        imgElem.setAttribute("src", imgURL);
        imgElem.setAttribute("width", imgWidth);
        imgElem.setAttribute("height", imgHeight);
        // Set the lockup element text from the item
        titleElem.setAttribute("class", "showTextOnHighlight");
        titleElem.textContent = titleText;
        // Put the child nodes into the lockup
        lockupElem.setAttribute("itemID", itemID);
        lockupElem.appendChild(imgElem);
        lockupElem.appendChild(titleElem);
    }

    /*
     * Called when a search result is selected, passing in the
     * JSON Object that was returned by the API for the result.
     */
    function handleSelectionForItem(item) {
        console.log("handleSelectionForItem: " + JSON.stringify(item));
        // Do something more interesting than logging
    }
}
}
registerAttributeName('searchDocumentURL', SearchController);
```